# Using plt.annotate() , how to adjust arrow color

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to add some annotations and arrows to my plots using [plt.annotate()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) and I am not sure how to change the arrow parameters.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'weight': [10, 10, 20, 5, 10, 15]})

print(df)
```

Dummy Data:

```
   weight
0      10
1      10
2      20
3       5
4      10
5      15
```

Plot Line:

```
ax = df.plot(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.annotate("Maximum", xy=(2, 20), xytext=(2, 10),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"), color='red')
```

[image: Test Line Chart]

How do I change the arrow color and other parameters to also match the Text? In this case I changed the text color to red.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **arrowprops** you should be able to set arrow color and other properties , something like this:

```
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle= '->',
                         color='red',
                         lw=3,
                         ls='--')
```